# Submit form in steps via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form that looks like this below in a PHP file (inside Wordpress plugin). The form is also processed inside of this same file.

I am wanting to save this form in "steps".  For example, user will select 4-5 choices on page 1, then I want AJAX to post choices. Then user proceeds to page 2, choices are again saved, etc. Last page will have a CAPTCHA for the final submission (if that even matters, I don't know in this specific case).

I am wanting to use the entire interface as one single form, and then hide/show each page inside of a `<div>` using jQuery.

I would like to know:

1) How to submit user choices using AJAX for this specific type of form.

2) What is the most efficient way of navigating through this form in "steps"?

3) I also want each page to operate independently when it comes to form validation. Is it possible to do this?

```
            <form id="quotation_form" name="form" action="#" method="post">
              <div id="page1">
              <div id="step0_header" class="steps-headers" onClick="step0ToggleClick();">Step 1<span style="margin-left:30px;">Sun Exposure</span></div>
                <div id="step0" class="quotation-steps"><strong>Describe the sun exposure of your planter...</strong><br/>
                  <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="sun_exposure" id="sun_exposure_sunny_most" value="sunny_most"<?php checked( 'sunny_most',$_POST['sun_exposure']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Sunny most of the day</label><br class="clear"/></div>
                  <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="sun_exposure" id="sun_exposure_shady_morning" value="shady_morning"<?php checked( 'shady_morning',$_POST['sun_exposure']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Shady Morning (Sunny Afternoon)</label><br class="clear"/></div>
                  <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="sun_exposure" id="sun_exposure_sunny_morning" value="sunny_morning"<?php checked( 'sunny_morning',$_POST['sun_exposure']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Sunny Morning (Shady Afternoon)</label><br class="clear"/></div>
                  <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="sun_exposure" id="sun_exposure_shady_most" value="shady_most"<?php checked( 'shady_most',$_POST['sun_exposure']); ?> /><label class="label-quotation-steps">Shady most of the day</label><br class="clear"/><br class="clear"/></div>
                </div>

                <div id="step1_header" class="steps-headers" onClick="step1ToggleClick();">Step 2<span style="margin-left:30px;">Height</span></div>
                  <div id="step1" class="quotation-steps"><strong>What is the height of your planter?</strong><br /> 
                    <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="height" id="height_1" value="height_1"<?php checked( 'height_1',$_POST['height']); ?>/><label class="label-quotation-steps">8 to 14 inches</label><br class="clear"/></div>
                    <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="height" id="height_2" value="height_2"<?php checked( 'height_2',$_POST['height']); ?>/><label class="label-quotation-steps">15 to 20 inches</label><br class="clear"/></div>
                    <div class="radio-container"><input type="radio" name="height" id="height_3" value="height_3"<?php checked( 'height_3',$_POST['height']); ?>/><label class="label-quotation-steps">21 inches or more</label><br class="clear"/><br class="clear"/></div>
                  </div>

                  <input type="button" name="get_quote" id="get_quote" value="Save choices and continue..." class="request_quotation_btn" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
               </div> <!-- #page1 -->

               <div id="page2">
                 <!-- Page2 stuff will go here, and is located in this same form. -->
               </div>
             </form>
```

Comment: Have a look : http://www.smarttutorials.net/multi-step-signup-form-using-jquery-ajax-php-html5-and-css3/

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon some neat code implementing form wizards. (so with steps: 1,2,3)
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/

Take a look at the source code of the demo. The actual library is called `formToWizard.js`

1. by using this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ plugin. (you could also use plain js, of course)
2. this is also provided by the library. (#link 1)
3. depends on your
   validation mechanism.